# What is the best way prevent duplicate records in a SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

what is the best way to prevent duplicate records in a SQL Server database? Using triggers? Using a unique constraint?

Comment: Use unique index or constraint

Comment: you will get thousands of answers, if Google it!

Comment: As a *general rule*, I'd recommend using features which are designed and dedicated to a particular usage in preference to using triggers. Only use triggers if the other DRI features aren't able to achieve your overall goals.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? It seems like a fair question to me. I *did* Google it, and this post came up. That's good for Stack Overflow, right?

Comment: @Shana: If an answer was helpful, please upvote or mark it as answered.

Answer (score 9):

Use unique constraints on one or more columns in the table.
Example:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL UNIQUE,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
FirstName varchar(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

Alter existing table as below

```
ALTER TABLE Persons
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_PersonID UNIQUE (P_Id,LastName)
```

If you are using a front-end application to populate the table in the database. Do your validation select query from the application on the database to check for duplicates before inserting into the database. Using constraints will prevent duplicates by throwing an exception.

**Note: The above example is SQL SERVER, Oracle, ms access**

For much more indepth solution see [How to prevent duplicate records being inserted with SqlBulkCopy when there is no primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593689/how-to-prevent-duplicate-records-being-inserted-with-sqlbulkcopy-when-there-is-n?rq=1)

Comment: @Chukwu can you please give me example. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want error throw from unique constraint and you also want database to receive duplicated data but insert nothing. You may look at merge statement

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396